# Search Directory for specific file type and return true or false if it exists in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filter, get-childitem

Now this is probably a very simple fix, but I can't seem to get it. I'm trying to search a directory and it's sub-folders for a specific file type. My code currently returns as true if the file exists, but I'm trying to also have it return false on the terminal. Below is my code

```
Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\$kit" -recurse -include "*.pem"| ForEach-Object {Test-Path $_}
```

Now this will return as `true` on the terminal for the folder that does have the PEM file. But I'd like to have it also return as `false` on the terminal for the folder that doesn't have the file, as I am planning on using the `true` and `false` to perform different sets of code.

Comment: wait... this should already return $false as well... The reason it's never returning false is because you're already implicitly testing for the existence by returning a list of objects, via Get-ChildItem that Windows is providing that will always exist...  so you're never getting a false because all of the objects you're passing it are already known to exist.

Comment: right, the issue I guess I'm mainly running into is I can get it to return ``$true`` and ``$false`` but it checks every file in each folder and will return 1 true and 8 falses. I'm more trying to find out if the specific file extension exists in the folders return ``$true`` and return ``$false`` if it doesn't exist. so Ultimately it'll show 1 ``$true`` and 1 ``$false``

Comment: So for clarification, what you're after is more knowing what directory contains .PEM files and you want to report what directories have how many PEM files in them?

Comment: Right, I'm looking to know if a Directory has a PEM file or not. 
What I'm ultimately trying to do is; If it **does** have a PEM file it'll do Y and if it **doesn't** have a PEM file it'll do step X then Y.

Comment: That should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Source'

foreach ($d in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $s -Directory:$true)) {
    if ($d.GetFiles('*.pem')) { 
        $true 
    } else { 
        $false 
    }
}
```

This should get you started... I really wish PowerShell had a built-in ternary construct...

Comment: PowerShell 7 has a ternary operator: [https://toastit.dev/2019/09/25/ternary-operator-powershell-7/](https://toastit.dev/2019/09/25/ternary-operator-powershell-7/)

Comment: I do have PS 7, so I will look into the ternary operator thing. I'm not too sure if I'll use it since I still have to support 5.1. But Thank you for the start and I think I can make that work to my needs!

Comment: Ternary implementation: `@($($True),$($False))[!$false]` or shown by @shadow2020. $() subexpression operator can contain any expression.

Comment: I don't think ternary implementation is worth it. Nothing wrong with simple `if..else` code. Its readable and easy to understand.

Comment: I was more lamenting it for my own use than wanting to use it in this example... but fair note.

Answer (score 3):

This one is easy. If $target_files has a value it returns true, if not returns false.

```
$target_files = Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\$kit" -recurse -include "*.pem"

if($target_files){
    write-host "This returns true if there are files."
}
else{
    write-host "This returns false if there are no files."
}
```

If you have powershell 7 you can use ternary operator, however not all of us have powershell 7, hence here is a quicker shorter way to achive this also if you're not into the IF/ELSE method. $result will return a true or false depending if the files are there or not.

```
$target_files = Get-ChildItem "$ScriptPath\$kit" -recurse -include "*.pem"
$result = (${true}, ${false})[-NOT $target_files]
```